# Why is "one" pronounced as "wan", not "oh-ne"?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is *one* pronounced as "wan", not "oh-ne"? Why are the spelling and pronunciation of *one* so strange?

In French, *one* is written as *un*, and pronounced as "oe" (with nasal sound). The sound is similar to French. Is this English word affected by French?

Comment: If it followed normal English conventions for VCe words, “one” would be a homophone of “own”.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Etymonline has [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=one&searchmode=none):

> Originally pronounced as it still is in *only*, and in dial. *good 'un*, *young 'un*, etc.; the now-standard pronunciation "wun" began c.14c. in southwest and west England (Tyndale, a Gloucester man, spells it *won* in his Bible translation), and it began to be general 18c.

Wiktionary [adds](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one#Pronunciation):

> *one* and *once* are pronounced differently from the related words *alone*, *only* and *atone*. Stressed vowels often become diphthongs over time (Latin *bona* → Italian *buona* and Spanish *buena*), and this happened in the late Middle Ages to the words *one* and *once*, first recorded ca 1400: the vowel underwent some changes, from *ōn* → *ōōōn* → *wōn* → *wōōn* → *wŏŏn* → *wŭn*.

It is worth noting that *one* comes from the same source as the indefinite articles *an* and *a* (of which *an* is actually the older form). It is cognate with the Latin *unus* — whence the French *un* you mention (and the Spanish *un*, and the Portuguese *um*...) — as well as with the German *ein*, the Russian *один*, etc.

Comment: So does this mean (as I'm not quite sure what the notation in the last bit means) that _originally_, i.e. in Old English, "one" was indeed pronounced like "own"?

Answer (score 1):

The word *one* would be expected to be pronounced /oʊn/ in modern English based on either its spelling or its etymology. The pronunciations starting with /w/ are exceptional. As far as I know, the use of /w/ in this word is not related to French in any way. As RegDwigнt's answer says, French *un* is similar in form to English *one* because the two words are cognates.

A 2013 blog post by Piotr Gąsiorowski, "[The Secret Ways of Weak Forms: Here Comes a New ’Un](http://langevo.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-secret-ways-of-weak-forms-here.html)", indicates that /w/ may have been inserted at the start of other words beginning with rounded vowels in older stages of English, but that *one* (and *once*) is the only surviving example of this phenomenon.

> There is spelling evidence to show that some varieties of Middle English tended to insert a glide before any word-initial vowel, as if trying to force every word to begin with a consonant. The glide tended to match the features of the vowel, so we usually find the rounded back glide /w/ before rounded back vowels, including ME /ɔː/. Middle English scribes had no common standard to conform to, so they often used “ear-spellings”, revealing their pronunciation habits. We thus find occasional w-initial variants of words like *ǭte* ‘oat’, *ǭth* ‘oath’, *ǭn* ‘one’, *ǭnes* ‘once’, *ǭnliche* or *ǭnlie* ‘only’, *ǭld* ‘old’, *ǭk* ‘oak’, etc. The idealised “dictionary” spellings cited in the preceding sentence represent a Late Middle English “virtual norm” that didn’t really exist. The actual spelling was highly variable, and the documented variants include *wote, woth, won, wonys, wonlyche, wolde, wooke,* etc.

Answer (score -3):

At times in middle English, the word was written "oon". If you pronounce both o's separately, you end up with the sound "wu". Go to Wiktionary for a very complete explanation.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. If I pronounce both Os separately, I end up with an /ɔʔɔ/, not a /wu/. (Also, the Wiktionary explanation is already quoted in its entirety elsewhere on this page, while you forgot to so much as link to the page we are supposed to go to.)